# Uploading local file to a Data Management hub

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

i'm using forge-directToS3 git sample NodeJs version, w/ the following errors:

1. for BIM 360 project
   `node.exe test/upload-to-hub.js ./upload/FindColumns-Basic_hub.rvt b.3ce14781-7572-430f-8fdb-a84c05bca41f urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.pbFqE__hSIKiFcbmLhNsBw eyJ...`
   {
   status: 403,
   text: `{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"644f7bb4-046c-4d86-a618-009bdde9beea","status":"403","code":"FOLDER_VIOLATION","detail":"Type 'items:autodesk.core:File' is not allowed in folder"}]}`,
   method: 'POST',
   path: '/data/v1/projects/b.3ce14781-7572-430f-8fdb-a84c05bca41f/items'
   },
2. for acc project

   https://acc.autodesk.com/docs/files/projects/b565ed9f-6178-42a7-bafd-8a48d1ea9804?folderUrn=urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.folder%3Aco.iKMXjz0hS1aZ5rGOZ3_ppA&viewModel=detail&moduleId=folders
   `node.exe test/upload-to-hub.js ./upload/FindColumns-Basic_hub.rvt b.b565ed9f-6178-42a7-bafd-8a48d1ea9804 urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.folder%3Aco.iKMXjz0hS1aZ5rGOZ3_ppA eyJ...`
   {
   status: 400,
   text: '{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"288f6e68-6590-4e11-9500-5c2cd0eb5e07","status":"400","code":"BAD_INPUT","title":"One or more input values in the request were bad","detail":"Relationship does not have an id."}]}',
   method: 'POST',
   path: '/data/v1/projects/b.b565ed9f-6178-42a7-bafd-8a48d1ea9804/storage'
   },

any reason behind it and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message shows, `items:autodesk.core:File` is not allowed for BIM360 Docs or Autodesk Docs (ACC). The `core` is for Fusion Team and the old BIM360 platform called BIM360 Team.

For BIM360, item extension is `items:autodesk.bim360:File` and version extension is `versions:autodesk.bim360:File`.

See https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document-s3/

For the second issue, you must decode your folder id from `urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.folder%3Aco.iKMXjz0hS1aZ5rGOZ3_ppA` to `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.iKMXjz0hS1aZ5rGOZ3_ppA`. In JavaScript, you can use `decodeURIComponent( encdoedUrlString )`